# Что обозначает action="#vote"?

Tags: html

Вот форма `<form method="post" action="#vote" id="voteform">`, что обозначает `#vote`? Я прочитал, что action должен принимать путь к скрипту обработчике. Как в таком случае понимать #vote?

Comment: если текущий скрипт  `http://example.com/simple.php`, то action вызовет `http://example.com/simple.php#vote`

Comment: @splash58  Я что-то совсем не понял ваш ответ. Как это текущий скрипт с расширение .php? Запрос отправляется из html формы, то есть из файла с расширением .html. Также мне не понятна запись simple.php#vote.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: @splash58 я понимаю как это работает с html документом, но как якорь может действовать в simple.php

Comment: url вы же можете получить в php, сзначит можете его как-то обработать. зачем это в это в этом коде - не знаю. Может, чтоб знать, какая форма вызвала страницу, может, чтоб ее отмотать потом до нужного места